# Is a join equivalent to a filtered cartesian product?

Tags: sql, oracle

If you want to join two tables there are essentialy two ways of doing that:

the "correct", didactical way:

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
```

and the dirty way:

```
select * from t1,t2 where t1.col1=t2.col1
```

both of them lead to the same result but are they equivalent also in terms of performance? I would still prefer the first way because it is the one that intuitively makes more sense to me: people came up with the join clause for a reason and I can immediately distinguish a select from a join.

But, truth to be said, I saw a lot of queries made with the second way and I'm wondering why people do that...

Comment: Both variants return a subset of the cartesian product and are equivalent.

Comment: They are not exactly equivalent.  One uses **standard**, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The other uses archaic syntax that has been out-of-fashion for decades.  They do return the same result set and probably generate the same execution plan.